# Customizing force.drag loses sticky nodes on hover

Tags: javascript, d3.js, drag, force-layout

The d3.js source in /src/layout/force.js has an early return if you customize force layout dragging:

```
  force.drag = function() {
    if (!drag) drag = d3.behavior.drag()
        .origin(d3_identity)
        .on("dragstart.force", d3_layout_forceDragstart)
        .on("drag.force", dragmove)
        .on("dragend.force", d3_layout_forceDragend);

    if (!arguments.length) return drag;

    this.on("mouseover.force", d3_layout_forceMouseover)
        .on("mouseout.force", d3_layout_forceMouseout)
        .call(drag);

  };
```

It will skip the sticky hover code when the simulation is running. You can see it on this demo http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3750558. When you get the simulation to move around a lot and try to stop a node by hovering over it, they no longer stop.

I have a work around that I am using like so:

```
force.drag()
   .on('dragstart', function(d) {
      //...
   })
   .on('dragend', function(d) {
      //...
   }) ;

//...

node.call(force.drag);
```

This code will call the early return version of force.drag first so you can listen for events, then call the default version to get the extra mouse behavior. The second call skips the drag events section because it was already registered, which is unexpectedly good for this case.

Here is the code I would like to use, but you will lose the sticky nodes on hover functionality:

```
var drag = force.drag()
   .on('dragstart', function(d) {
      //...
   })
   .on('dragend', function(d) {
      //...
   }) ;

//...

node.call(drag);
```

The reason I didn't just use my own d3.behavior.drag is because I wanted to use as much of the force layout's d.fixed handling as possible.

Does anyone know why the code has an early return when you want to customize the dragging? My workaround is very fragile for future force drag changes. Unfortunately moving the return to the bottom might break some people's simulations.

Comment: I'm not sure that the question is. Regardless of whether you want to customize or not, you always need to attach it to the elements you want it to be active one by calling it with the corresponding selection. So your workaround looks to me like the code you would use in any case. What code do you want to use instead?

Comment: I added what I would like my code to look like if the early return was at the end.

Comment: Your workaround is exactly how you're supposed to do it (have a look at the many examples, e.g. [here](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4062045)). It seems that all you'd be saving is the `.drag` at the end, which makes it explicit that you're attaching the drag behaviour as opposed to the force layout itself.

Comment: Your example doesn't tack on any drag event listeners. If you were to do that, you would lose the sticky hover functionality.

Comment: The nodes in that example are sticky on hover. And try dragging them.

Comment: You're missing the fact that this issue requires you to tack on additional drag event listeners. The link in my question, http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3750558, suffers from this problem. No more sticky on hover because of extra drag event handlers.

Comment: Ok, I'm lost now -- what is it that you want to do? You would just need to set `.fixed` on `mouseover` to get the behaviour you want, wouldn't you? How is this related to how you attach the drag behaviour?

Comment: This is a question about d3 internal design. It seems if the early return was moved to the end of the function, all the sticky logic would be preserved. Is it a bug, or is there a reason for it?

Comment: The latter part of that function attaches the drag behaviour to a set of elements by establishing the listeners. When you call it without any arguments, `this` wouldn't be a selection and the code wouldn't do what you intended (and quite likely give you an error).

Comment: Ah yes, I see now. Thanks for going through the trouble to understand my question. If you post that last comment as an answer, I will accept it.

Comment: Great, I'll do that. Sorry that it took so long, but I didn't get what you were after at first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The latter part of the `force.drag` function attaches the drag behaviour to a set of elements by establishing the listeners. When you call it without any arguments, this wouldn't be a selection and the code wouldn't do what you intended (and quite likely give you an error). Therefore, it checks that and returns if there's nothing to attach listeners to.